# PHP + MySQL - one table holding reference to IDs from multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, relational-database

I just would like to know what are the most common approaches to get a table to hold a reference to IDs from multiple tables.

I have a system with modules like customers, suppliers, orders, etc. and I would like to add a "Notes" functionality to all of those modules to be able to add/read notes.

As one customer/supplier/order can have multiple notes, I have chosen the one-to-many relation way and so the notes in their table should refer to the particular item id in a separate column.
But as I will refer to IDs from multiple tables, their IDs will be overlapping and I need a way to say in which particular table to search for that ID.

I don't want to create exact the same notes module for each of my modules and here I could concentrate notes in one table. Those notes differ only in the fact, to which module they belong to.

Shall I

- store the particular table name in the notes table? But that name can
  change later and the system will break
- introduce something like UNIQUE ID or a hash to all of my modules,
  which  would be unique among different tables and store it's id in
  the notes table?
- create separate notes table for every module and don't worry about
  code/class/table duplication?

Thanks for your ideas!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We do something similar with notes that can be attached to many objects.  Each of our objects has a unique class id (we store each type of object in it's own table), and we store the unique class id + specific object id in the notes table.

We then just have to maintain a lookup of unique class id -> table name.  By using the unique class id + object id as the key we ensure that the same id in different tables isn't an issue.

Comment: Thanks Alan, can you please explain the "specific object id" a bit more? Do you have a table with all your classes having their own ID? Like Orders have ID 1, Customers have ID 2, etc.?

Comment: Orders might have a unique class id of "12345" and Customers has "67890".  We could add notes to both order id 123 and customer id 123, and the respective keys on the notes table would be "12345_123" and "67890_123" (actually, we store the unique id and the object id in separate columns).